# Adding columns in one dataframe from calculations based on other dataframe using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 like:

```
  cycleName quarter  product        qty  price sell/buy

0       2020      q3    wood           10   100   sell

1       2020      q3    leather        5    200   buy

2       2020      q3    wood           2    200   buy

3       2020      q4    wood          12   40   sell 

4       2020      q4    leather       12   40   sell

5       2021      q1    wood          12   80   sell 

6       2021      q2    leather       12   90   sell
```

And another dataframe df2 as below. It has unique products of df1:

```
  product        currentValue

0     wood           20

1     leather        50
```

I want to create new column in df2, called income which will be based on calculations on df1 data. Example if product is wood the income2020 will be created seeing if cycleName is 2020 and if sell/buy is sell then add quantity * price else subtract quantity * price.

### product        currentValue  income2020

0     wood           20       10 * 100 - 2 * 200 + 12 *  40 (=1080)

1     leather        50       -5 * 200 + 12 * 40 (= -520)

I have a problem statement in python, which I am trying to do using pandas dataframes, which I am very new to.

I am not able to understand how to create that column in df2 based on different conditions on df1.

Answer (score 1):

You can map `sell` as 1 and `buy` as -1 using [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) then multiply columns `qty`, `price` and `sell/buy` using [`df.prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) to get only `2020` `cycleName` values use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and groupby by `product` and take sum using [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
df_2020 = df.query('cycleName == 2020').copy() # `df[df['cycleName'] == 2020].copy()`
df_2020['sell/buy'] = df_2020['sell/buy'].map({'sell':1, 'buy':-1})
df_2020[['qty', 'price', 'sell/buy']].prod(axis=1).groupby(df_2020['cycleName']).sum()

product
leather    -520
wood       1080
dtype: int64
```

Note:

- Use `.copy` else you would get `SettingWithCopyWarning`
- To maintain the order use `sort=False` in `df.groupby`

  ```
  (df_2020[['qty', 'price', 'sell/buy']].
      prod(axis=1).
      groupby(df_2020['product'],sort=False).sum()
  )

  product
  wood       1080
  leather    -520
  dtype: int64
  ```